# Bundling errors after updating an npm package in React Native app

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm

I'm building a React Native app which, at this point, doesn't have too many dependencies.

Every time I update an outdated npm package, I am GUARANTEED to run into bundling errors. It could be any package. I then spend hours trying different ways to clear npm cache, project cache, etc.

Does anyone else have this issue? Is there a "standard" set of commands I should run after upgrading ANY npm package? This is extremely frustrating!

This screen shot shows today's flavor of the issue:
[image]

BTW, I'm on Windows 10, using VS Code. My React Native version is 0.63.1, Node version is 14.7.0 and npm version is 6.14.7

UPDATE:
After a couple of hours of messing around and removing `node_modules` folder several times and issuing the following commands a few times, it's now started to work. Unfortunately, I can't put my finger on what fixed it. As I said, I did the same things a few times.

Here are the steps I repeated a few times -- though once should be enough:

1. Deleted the `node_modules` folder
2. In root folder, I ran `npm cache clean --force`
3. I then reinstalled all npm packages by running `npm i`
4. Went into `cd android` folder and ran `./gradlew clean`
5. Then in project root, I ran `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Unfortunately, doing this the first time didn't fix the issue. It looks like I have to waste a couple of hours for things to get back to normal! Any idea how to make this problem go away for good?

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is that you have not start the metro bundle. Try `react-native start` and then re-run the app